# How to call jQuery function from normal JS function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sample

How to call jQuery function from normal JS function? ( A + B Sample needed)

So I need a jQuery function adding varA to varB.
And a JS function which could call that jQuery function sending varA and varB to It and reciving result.

Comment: What do you mean by a "jQuery function"?

Comment: You don't need jQuery to add varA to varB - could you clarify why you want to use jQuery, or are you just looking for a "Hello, World" example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery functions are normal javascript functions.

So, you just call it like a "normal" function like in the following example using jQuery's `trim()`.

```
    function isStringEmpty(str){
                             // jquery function
        return str!==null && jQuery.trim(str).length > 0;
    }
    alert(isStringNullorEmpty("hello")); //alerts false
    alert(isStringNullorEmpty("")); //alerts true
```

Comment: This post is old and I'm not talking about the main subject but : your function `isStringEmpty` should be named `isStringNotEmpty` w/ this implementation. Just saying.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery functions *are* normal javascript: jQuery is just a file that includes a bunch of extremely well-written and useful javascript functions.

You can [view the (100% javascript) source for the latest release here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js).

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery function **is** a normal JavaScript function.

```
 function myFunction () {
     function_name(); // and / or
     object.property_name();
 }

 myFunction();
```